# How do I specify subnet and VPC IDs in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-cloudformation

I want my CloudFormation template to use existing subnets and VPCs. I don't want to create new ones.

How do I parameterize these?

When I look at the docs for `AWS::EC2::VPC` and `AWS::EC2::Subnet`, it seems these resources are only for creating *new* VPCs and subnets. Is that correct?

Should I just point the instance resource directly to the existing VPC and subnets I want it to use?

For example - if I have an instance resource in my template and I point it directly to an existing subnet, like this:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "MyServer": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "InstanceType": {
          "Ref": "InstanceType"
        },
"SubnetId": {
  "Ref": "subnet-abc123"
},
...
```

I get this error when validating the template:

```
Template contains errors.: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [subnet-abc123] in the Resources block of the template
```

I tried to do this with mappings but still getting an error:

```
  "Mappings": {
    "SubnetID": {
      "TopKey": {
        "Default": "subnet-abc123"
      }
    }
```

And with this in the instance resource:

```
"SubnetId": {
  "Fn::FindInMap": [
    "SubnetID",
    {
      "Ref": "TopKey"
    },
    "Default"
  ]
}
```

I get this error when trying to validate:

```
Template contains errors.: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [TopKey] in the Resources block of the template
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you wish to use a **specific VPC and subnet**, just insert their values:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "MyServer": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
        "SubnetId": "subnet-abc123",
        "ImageId": "ami-abcd1234"
      }
    }
}
```

A subnet always belongs to a VPC, so specifying the subnet will automatically select the matching VPC.

Answer (score 5):

Specify them in the `Parameters` section, and refer them in `Resources` section. CF will let you select the **VPC** first and then the **Subnet**.

```
  "Parameters" : {

    "VpcId" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
      "Description" : "VPCId of Virtual Private Cloud (VPC).",
      "Default" : ""
    },

    "VpcSubnet": {
      "Description" : "SubnetId in VPC",
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id",
      "Default" : ""
    },


  "Resources" : {
    ...
    "Ec2Instance" : {
      "Properties" : {
        "SubnetId" : { "Ref" : "VpcSubnet" },
```

Comment: But how do I point it to VPCs and subnets that already exist? I see no where in your example where I can plug in my existing subnet and VPC IDs a la vpc-abc123 or subnet-123456

Comment: You will specify them as values in the parameter.  If you try this with the AWS console then the UI will actually present the options to you in the HTML form.  Just give this solution a try and you'll see how it works.