# AWS CloudFormation - Launch EC2 instance in default VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I want to host a solution (CloudFormation template) on AWS market-place. When a user wants to spin up an instance using my solution, he is expected to select **only** the AWS region. I want the template to figure out the default VPC for that region and the default subnet for one of the AZ; at the moment, the choice of AZ does not matter. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324362/how-do-i-specify-the-subnet-and-vpc-ids-in-cloudformation) requires that the values be input to the template when creating it. However, my requirement is to have those values figured out auto-magically.

I know I can automate the look-up of defaults from Python SDK as shown below. I can also feed the output of this script to [troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) to get my final template. Even if I get this done, how do I host this 'dynamic' template on the market-place? Please note that, the CloudFormation template is important and therefore, I am not looking Chef or Puppet based solutions.

```
"""
    Documentation
"""
#
import json
import boto3
#
def get_default_vpc_id():
    """
        Get default VPC of a region. The region parameter is read from the AWS configuration file.
        The `boto3` SDK will look for the configuration file here - `$HOME/.aws/config`.
    """
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
    default_vpc = ec2_client.describe_vpcs(Filters=[{'Name' : 'isDefault', 'Values' : ['true']}])
    default_vpc_id = default_vpc['Vpcs'][0]['VpcId']

    return default_vpc_id
#
def get_vpc_subnets(vpc_id):
    """
        Get subnet and its details for the provided VPC identifier. The region parameter is read
        from the AWS configuration file. The `boto3` SDK will look for the configuration file here -
        `$HOME/.aws/config`.

        Since the VPC identifier, provided in this code, is the default VPC of a region, its
        subnets will be public. Therefore, there is no check for Internet Gateway.

        TODO: Include check of Internet Gateway and NAT Gateway.
    """
    ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
    default_vpc_id = ec2_resource.Vpc(vpc_id)
    vpc_subnets = default_vpc_id.subnets.all()
    #
    subnet_array = []
    for ec2_subnet in vpc_subnets:
        subnet = {}
        subnet['subnet_id'] = ec2_subnet.subnet_id
        subnet['subnet_az'] = ec2_subnet.availability_zone
        subnet['default_for_az'] = ec2_subnet.default_for_az
        subnet_array.append(subnet)
    #
    subnets = json.dumps(subnet_array)
    return subnets
#
def default_vpc_subnets():
    """
        Get subnets of the default VPC of a AWS region
    """
    default_vpc_id = get_default_vpc_id()
    subnets = get_vpc_subnets(default_vpc_id)
    subnets_of_default_vpc = json.dumps({'default_vpc_id' : default_vpc_id, 'subnets' : subnets})
    #
    print subnets_of_default_vpc
#
default_vpc_subnets()
```

Comment: Do you have to specify the VPC ID in CFT? Try without VPC ID, it should default into default VPC.

Comment: Will try that and report.

Comment: Test the case where the default VPC or subnet has been deleted.

Comment: @cogitoergosum Were you able to resolve this?